# Are there set rules you can apply to efficiently get an equation in Matrix-form from a summed equation?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Take for instance this equation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N C_{ir} \left[\frac{y_i-\sum_{s=1}^n C_{is}a_s}{\sigma_i^2}\right]=0\ ,\forall r$$

How do I transform this into an equation where, instead of summing over all the indices, I can just have multiplication of matrices and vectors?

I know how to do it, but my way seems a bit too simple: I look at the size of the matrices and just see what I need to transpose and what order I need to make the equation work. I'm not sure if this is the correct way and if this will always give the correct result.

Comment: The reason you saw $\displaystyle\Sigma_{i=1}^N$ rather than $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N$ is that you used \Sigma rather than $\sum$.  (A third form, $\sum_{i=1}^N$, is seen when \sum is used in a inline setting as opposed to a displayed setting.)  I changed it to \sum. ${}\qquad{}$